# Is there a way to mock Mule SAP outbound endpoint?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mule, bapi, munit

How to mock Mule SAP outbound endpoint calling a BAPI function and expecting synchronous response back? Is there a library? I am using Mule 3.4.2

Comment: Can't you just use a test flow serving a pre-baked BAPI response over HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try to [MUnit](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/MUnit). With it you can do things like:

```
<mock:when messageProcessor="mule:set-payload">
  <mock:with-attributes>
    <mock:with-attribute whereValue="#['Real Set Payload']" name="doc:name"/>
  </mock:with-attributes>
  <mock:then-return payload="#['mocked_payload']"/> (1)
</mock:when>
```